# Primefaces Maven Repository SSL certificate issues

Tags: java, maven, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

**Problem**

Using Primefaces maven repository for themes (org.primefaces.themes), some computers had troubles while building the project.

> Error transferring file: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

**Temporary Solution**

It appears that the primefaces repository SSL certificate was not accepted by Java on some machines (jdk version ?). Using keytool, i was able to fix this by adding the https://repository.primefaces.org/ SSL certificate to the lib/security/cacerts file in the JDK.

The problem is, that doing it, fix the problem for the current version of JDK but when i will update it, i will probably have to re-add the certificate to the new cacerts java file.

Have you any ideas to fix this permanently ?

The problem has been observed using the following maven/java versions:
maven 3.5.2 java 1.8.0_151
maven 3.5.2 java 1.8.0_162

Thanks !

Comment: Some had a problem, some didn't.  So the ones  that did not were most likely newer.  And hence it is already permanently fixed... right?